# model the probabilistic distribution of the data points using gaussian mixture model

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, gaussian

if I had a data point-set as $X$ consisting
of $\left\{x_{i} : i=1,2,....,N\right\}$

Gaussian clusters centers $V$ consisting of points
$\left\{v_{a} : a=1,2,.....,K\right\}$

and their covariance matrices
$\left\{\Sigma_a : a=1,2,.....mk\right\}$

the probability of the point $x_{i}$ given cluster $v_{a}$ is $p(x_{i}|v_{a})=$gaussian_distribution with ($v_a$-$x_i$) as a mean and $\Sigma_a $ as a covariance matrix

and probability of cluster $v_{a}$ given point $x_{i}$ is $p(v_{a}|x_{i})=\pi_{a,i}$

the probabilistic distribution model of all the data set X is
$$ 
p(X,V)=\prod_{i=1}^N \sum_{a=1}^{K} \pi_{a,i}p(x_{i}|v_{a},\Sigma_{a})
$$
if I understand correctly
then
$$
p(x_{i}|V)=\sum_{a=1}^{K}\pi_{a,i}p\left(x_{i}|v_{a},\Sigma_{a}\right)
$$
and
$$
p(X|v_{a})=\prod_{i=1}^N \pi_{a,i}p(x_{i}|v_{a},\Sigma_{a})
$$
then why the sets probability for example
$$
p(a|\{b,c,d\})=p(a|b)+p(a|c)+p(a|d)
$$
and
$$
p(\{a,b,c\}|d)=p(a|b)*p(a|c)*p(a|d)
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- $p(a,b,c)$ means $p(a\cap b\cap c) $ so
$$
p(a|\{b,c,d\})=p(a|b\cap c\cap d)=p(a|b)+p(a|c)+p(a|d)
$$

2- i didn't notice that the points in data points set are **independent** so
$$
p(\{a,b,c\}|d)=p(a|d)*p(b|d)*p(c|d)
$$